# Health Report with Alerts

Tags: alert, central-administration, health

I would like to create an alert on the central admin Health Reports list (`http://server:8080/Lists/HealthReports/AllItems.aspx`) if that is possible.

I have created an alert with:

- Change Type=All changes
- Send Alerts for These Changes=Anything changes
- When to Send Alerts=Send notification immediately

The alert seems to create okay, I get the standard creation email:

> 'xyz' has subscribed you for alert 'Review problems and solutions' on 'Central Administration'. 
>   You will receive alerts according to the delivery method, timing and criteria that were selected when the alert was created.
>   You can change this alert or any of your other alerts on the My Alerts on this Site page.

But then when I delete some of the warnings, and re-generate them, I don't get any alerts.

Has anyone got this working?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have created an alert with exactly the same settings. I have found this on technet (see [1]): Farm administrators can configure specific health rules to do the following:<br>
[...]<br>
- Receive e-mail alerts when problems are found.<br>
[...] Perhaps this means one can only create email alerts for specific rules.
This would confuse me, because I think the HealthReports is just another SharePoint list where you can create alerts ad libitum. Is it possible to create an alert on the list or only on single items? &nbsp; [1] http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/librar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem on my development instance.  I checked the job status for the Immediate Alerts job and there was not one listed for the Central Admin web application.

I opened up the SharePoint Management Shell and checked if this was enabled for the CA site with the following command

```
stsadm -o getproperty -pn job-immediate-alerts -url http://server:port
```

This command returned

```
<Property Exists="No"/>
```

So I set the property with the following command

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn job-immediate-alerts -pv "every 5 minutes between 0 and 59" -url http://server:port
```

I checked the job status in CA and there is now a job for Immediate Alerts for this web application.  After about 5 minutes the emails started appearing.

I checked a couple of other CA instances in our development environment and they were configured the same way.  It was at least off by default for our installation settings.

Comment: Was this in Sharepoint 2007, or 2010? I just tried that command on SharePoint 2010 and got "The server administration programs and the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web applications on this Web server are not compatible..." I haven't been able to find any equivalent in PowerShell.

Comment: This was on 2010 server edition.