# SharePoint 2013 Health Report List alerts not sending emails, job-immediate-alerts last run time N/A in CA

Tags: central-administration, alert, timer-jobs

We are trying to configure email alerts on the Central Admin Health Report list in SharePoint 2013. We get the confirmation email when the alert is first created, but nothing when a new error or warning arrives in the list.

Sure enough, no 'job-immediate-alert' existed on the CA webapp, as determined by viewing the CA UI Job definition page and the following powershell: `Get-SPTimerJob | ? {$_.name -like "*alert*"}`

To create the job on the CA webapp I followed the advice [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/health-report-with-alerts).  Now I can see in the Job Definition page the ‘Immediate Alerts’ job. ***However*, when I click to see details about the job the Last run time is N/A.**

I see the Immediate Alerts job scheduled in the Scheduled Jobs page, but the Job History page is empty.  I have tried to start the job manually with Powershell with the following:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$th = Get-SPTimerJob -WebApplication http://spsite:2013 | ? {$_.name -like "*alert*"} 
Start-SPTimerJob $th
```

No errors, but still the Last run time is N/A

Some users have said running the updatealerttemplates may help, so ran
`stsadm -o updatealerttemplates -url http://spsite:2013`
but the job still will not run.
I restarted the Timer Service via Windows Services as well, but still no luck.

No errors in Event Viewer or ULS.  **The job just seems to refuse to run on the CA Webapp**.
Anyone have any suggestions?  (Would rather not have to create a workflow just for this – this should be simple, right?)

**UPDATE:**
The servers restarted today, and the job-immediate-alerts timer job ran successfully TWICE on the SharePoint Central Administration v4 WebApp.  After running twice, something seems to prevent it from processing the job.  Very strange.

Comment: Sounds like this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d905ccbd-165a-46b2-ac6f-bd9d52dfd315/sharepoint-immediate-alert-issue-initial-alert-email-goes-through-however-subsequent-email-not?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious . Wonder why CA lists would have 'Alert Me' interface if it is unable to send an alert... is this just me?

Comment: run this one and see if the job enable for CA stsadm -o getproperty -pn job-immediate-alerts -url http://server:port

Comment: Yes, Property exists=yes and is set to run every five minutes.

Comment: Waqas, Did you guys ever come up with a root cause? I'm having the exact same issue. Thanks! Hi Waqas! Joe